# JQuery and Cookie: How to remove them when user leaves the page or exit window/tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I am learning to use this JQuery cookie plugin at
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

From what I have read, it's really easy to read and remove a cookie. My question is: I want the cookie to be removed when the user navigates away from the page or close the window/tab, how do I do that? How do I detect such activity?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
    // Remove the cookie
    $.cookie("name_of_cookie", null);
});
```

**Also, we have one more option:**

```
$(window).unload(function () {
    // Remove the cookie
    $.cookie("name_of_cookie", null);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I found that a fresh would also trigger this event. is there any way to retain the cookie when user do a F5 refresh?

Comment: Just track the `event` keycode, if it same as the `F5` keycode and don't do anything...

Answer (score 0):

The update to the accepted answer would be:

```
Cookies.remove('name');
```

With: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

The jQuery plugin is not longer mantained.